# Do succulents need to be kept out of the pot for some time before re-potting?

Tags: succulents, repotting

Some people recommend to leave the plants, in particular the Aloe Vera, lying down out of the pot without soil in its roots for up to 3 days before re-potting. But  I always come to find some people contradicting what I have just learned.

So, is this right? Is this for all succulents? Is it just for the Aloe Vera or for all potted plants in general? What's the rationale behind that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rationale is simply to allay as much chance for rot as possible. Succulents in particular are susceptible to rot and newly-broken roots from them, especially so.

Also, it's purported that the dry soil will encourage new root growth, strengthening the plant.

I would suggest that if there is any major breakage of any thick, fleshy roots, that any broken pieces be removed and that this method of allowing a few days to dry be used to allow the wound(s) to callous.

I believe that there is some exaggeration to this claim and as long as you don't water-log your newly potted plant you should be OK. Be sure to use a quality, well-draining soil mixture.

Answer (score 4):

It is not something you would do with any plants other than, possibly, succulents - none of the other plants like roses or herbaceous perennials or shrubs appreciate their roots being exposed to air for any length of time at all.